# Custom Redirect to Page With URL Parameters Using Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to redirect to another page with url parameters using Elementor form redirect action.

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
     
        //make sure its our form
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

    // Replace MY_FORM_NAME with the name you gave your form
    if ( 'test_form' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }
    

  global $wpdb, $post;

// Get Current Url Slug
 $post_slug = $post->post_name;

//redirect URL to be setup

$redirect_url = '/test2/'.$post_slug.'?f_name='.$fields['f_name'];

//add to record the redirect URL
$redirect_to = $record->replace_setting_shortcodes( $redirect_url );

// Set redirect action to handler
$handler->add_response_data( 'redirect_url', $redirect_to );
    
}, 10, 2);
```

It when trying to submit the form it shows an error message of "error" and in the debug log it shows "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add_response_data() on null"

I tried this code

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
     
        //make sure its our form
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

    // Replace MY_FORM_NAME with the name you gave your form
    if ( 'test_form' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }
    

  global $wpdb, $post;

// Get Current Url Slug
 $post_slug = $post->post_name;

//redirect URL to be setup

$redirect_url = '/test2/'.$post_slug.'?f_name='.$fields['f_name'];

//add to record the redirect URL
$redirect_to = $record->replace_setting_shortcodes( $redirect_url );

// Set redirect action to handler
$handler->add_response_data( 'redirect_url', $redirect_to );
    
}, 10, 2);
```

And I was expecting after the submission of the form to be redirected to http://example.com/test2/post-slug?f_name=test

Comment: You have defined the handler object as `$ajax_handler` but trying to use it with `$handler`, fix your object variable name and you'll not get an error.

Comment: @Vijay Hardaha Thank you! It had been a long day and I overlooked the error. I figured it out shortly after posting but forgot to update my post. I'm sorry for the delayed response. Anyway, I hope you have a great day.